# main() thread versus one created by pthread_create()

Tags: pthreads, program-entry-point

I've been creating programs exemplifying concurrency bugs using POSIX threads.

The overall question I have is what is the difference between the main() thread and one created by `pthread_create()`. My original understanding was that they are pretty much the same but, I'm getting different results from the two programs below.

To expand before showing the code I've written, what I am wondering is: Is there a difference between the following.

```
int main() {
    ...
    pthread_create(&t1, NULL, worker, NULL);
    pthread_create(&t2, NULL, worker, NULL);
    ...
}
```

and

```
int main() {
    ...
    pthread_create(&t1, NULL, worker, NULL);
    worker();
    ...
}
```

To expand using a full example program. I've made two versions of the same program. They both have the same function `worker()`

```
void *worker(void *arg) {
    printf("Entered worker function\n");
    int myid;

    int data = 999;

    pthread_mutex_lock(&gidLock);
    myid = gid;
    gid++;
    printf("myid == %d\n", myid);

    pthread_mutex_unlock(&gidLock);

    if (myid == 0) {
        printf("Sleeping since myid == 0\n");
        sleep(1);     
        result = data;
        printf("Result updated\n");
    }

    return NULL;
}
```

`gid` and `data` are globals initialized to 0.

What's the difference between the following `main()` functions

```
int main_1() {
    pthread_t t1, t2;
    int tmp;

    /* initialize globals */
    gid = 0;
    result = 0;

    pthread_create(&t1, NULL, worker, NULL);

    pthread_create(&t2, NULL, worker, NULL);

    pthread_join(t2, NULL);


    printf("Parent thread exited worker function\n");


    tmp = result;
    printf("%d\n", tmp);

    pthread_exit((void *) 0);
}
```

and

```
int main_2() {
    pthread_t t1;
    int tmp;

    /* initialize globals */
    gid = 0;
    result = 0;

    pthread_create(&t1, NULL, worker, NULL);

    worker(NULL);

    printf("Parent thread exited worker function\n");

    tmp = result;
    printf("%d\n", tmp);

    pthread_exit((void *) 0);
}
```

Sample output for `main_1()`

```
Entered worker function
myid == 0
Sleeping since myid == 0
Entered worker function
myid == 1
Parent thread exited worker function
0
Result Updated
```

Sample output for `main_2()`

```
Entered worker function
myid == 0
Sleeping since myid == 0
Entered worker function
myid == 1
/* program waits here */
Result updated
Parent thread exited worker function
999
```

**Edit:** The program intentionally has a concurrency bug (an atomicity violation). Delays were added by calling sleep() to attempt to force the buggy interleaving to occur. The intention of the program is to be used to test software automatically detecting concurrency bugs.

I would think that `main_1()` and `main_2()` are essentially the same program which should result in the same interleaving when run on the same system (or largely the same interleaving; it is indeterminate, but running the same program on the same system only tend explores a small section of the potential scheduling and rarely deviates [1]).

The "desired" output is is that from `main_1()`

I'm not sure why the thread with `myid == 1` stalls and does not return in `main_2()`. If I had to guess

Thanks for reading this far, and if anyone needs more information I'd be happy to oblige. Here are links to the full source code.

`main_1()`: https://gist.github.com/2942372

`main_2()`: https://gist.github.com/2942375

I've been compiling with `gcc -pthread -lpthread`

Thanks again.

[1] S. Park, S. Lu, Y. Zhou. "CTrigger: Exposing Atomicity Violation Bugs from Their Hiding Places"

Comment: In both of them you forgot to join t1. That leads to race conditions and unexpected result when examining output.

Comment: Sorry, the question wasn't clear, I've added edits to clarify. The program is intentionally buggy. The question I had (which again, sorry, I was not clear about originally) was if there is a conceptual difference between the two programs or if they are just consistently running into different schedulings.

Comment: they are just running into different timings. It looks deterministic because starting a thread takes so much time that the second program finishes before it. But in the first program you wait for the second thread that will only happen after the first thread.

Comment: @user1461005: are you asking if the race condition you've intentionally placed in the code will be guaranteed to always run in the order given in your two examples?  If so, the answer is no. (even if it seems that in many trial runs for these simple examples you do always get the same outputs).

Comment: Also, what makes you think that the thread with myid == 1 stalls when running `main_2()`? I think that thread prints out it's two lines of information then returns. The 'stall' you see is the main thread waiting in the `sleep()`.

Comment: @Dani: I didn't think at all about how pthread_create would take extra time to run, that probably explains it.